# monitoring new user

Tags: html, database, go, web-applications

I am a go student, so I am writing a simple API, that needs analytics
I want to create a monitoring new users, to see how many users had registered by specific period. So I set date (init date and end date) and return number of new users.

Here is my func only:

```
package db

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "time"
)

func NewUsersByPeriod(start time.Time, end time.Time) (count int) {
    Qselect := `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "User" WHERE datereg BETWEEN $1 and $2 ;`
    row := connectionVar.QueryRowx(Qselect, start, end)
    err := row.Scan(&count)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }

    return count
}
```

My question is about how to realize it correctly, what frameworks I could use?
Write any recommendation

Comment: Please allow me to clarify your question, so you want your app to spit out the result of this DB query in a RESTful manner? and you need a framework for this REST service?

Comment: I try to avoid using any framework, however I want to 
Yes, in restful manner
Action is like this: 
   In  http://cltloylprog.com/api/analytics/newusers
Analytic set the period(for instance Jan-1-2018 till March-1-2018) and as result on html page it shows new registrated users in table
   Month|Jan|Feb|Mar|
   Users | 12 |45  | 21|
I hope you got my idea

Answer (score 0):

I use gin-gonic for every RESTful API I make ( https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/ ). Whether is 1 QPS or 100,000 QPS, it's a solid performer, simple to use with great documentation.

You wouldn't want to use logrus.Fatal mind you as that would terminate the API. Use gin to handle the errors and output them using JSON or similar and the correct http code obviously.